# Can I use VSBuild@1 yaml task to restore multiple projects?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I need to restore 3 projects (csproj) using VSBuild yaml task. I know that I can do it if I add 3 yaml tasks, but I wonder if is there a way to restore them all using just one task.
I already tried like this:

```
  - task: VSBuild@1
    displayName: 'Restore projects'
    inputs:
      solution: "'**/Project1.csproj';'**/Project2.csproj'"
      msbuildArgs: '/t:Restore'
      vsVersion: $(VSVersion)
      platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(Configuration)'
```

,and I don't have syntax errors but the pipeline fails with this error: "Solution not found using search pattern..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSBuild task cannot recognize the multiple projects in this format `"'**/Project1.csproj';'**/Project2.csproj'"`. You can use the wildcards `**/Project*.csproj` to map your projects.

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Restore projects'
  inputs:
    solution: '**/Project*.csproj'
    msbuildArgs: '/t:Restore'
```

If your projects are dotnet core projects. You can use the [DotNetCoreCLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) task, which support multiple lines input:

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: |
     **/Project1.csproj
     **/Project2.csproj
     **/Project3.csproj
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you specify solution file(s) to build (e.g. *.sln) rather than individual projects. So if it's possible to provide a solution file name that includes those 3 projects you need, that would be the best approach.

If that doesn't fit your case, you can use wildcards to provide a mask that fits all 3 projects, for example, `**/Project*.csproj`.

As the last option, you can try to switch to the [MSBuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild?view=azure-devops) instead. In fact, [the docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops#faq) that:

> In some cases you might need to use the MSBuild task. For example, you should use it if you are building code projects apart from a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `MSBuild@1` task behaves exactly like the `VSBuild@1`task in that respect. It looks like you either have to create a dedicated `VSBuild@1` task for each project or create an MSBuild .proj script to include (and exclude if needed) your individual .csproj.